# Some keyboard keys stopped working when control pressed

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

All of a sudden, some keyboard shortcuts seem to have stopped working in applications. The two I'm noticing it for are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>. This is happening across multiple applications which should support those hotkeys.

I've tried running Spy++ to monitor the Windows messages, and it looks as if when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is pressed, no keyboard events are being sent for the <kbd>K</kbd> key press. However, pressing <kbd>K</kbd> without <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> does work.

This seems to be happening for the <kbd>W</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd> keys, and also <kbd>Arrow right</kbd>.

I've tried using Windows Hotkey Explorer, but there's nothing obvious registered in there.

Any ideas to what could have caused this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reinstalling the keyboard drivers and this fixed it.

(edit) Turns out that rebooting after installing the drivers has brought back the issue!